# Full Size Image on Column of AdvanceBandedGridView Devexpress

Tags: c#, grid, devexpress

How did they do this?

[image]

Is it AdvanceBandedGridView on Devexpress?

I tried using advbandedgridview but my Image Column wont Fill Fullsize.

[image]

im just simply set the Image repository to SizeMode = Stretch but seems only stretch on width but not on height.

Anyone could help me on this? please. thanks.

Comment: Provide more information to get that what you are doing wrong. why are you hiding header of you advance grid as you shown in the above image. if possible provide information about your grid layout settings too.. Image edit control right now acquired only cell rather than 2 vertical cells as shown in the above sample image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set icon column's [AutoFillDown Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridColumn_AutoFillDowntopic) to `true` and [RowCount Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridColumn_RowCounttopic) to 2 or 3 depend on number of rows you have created in the view to display a particular row from data.

As per the documentation of [BandedGridColumn.AutoFillDown Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridColumn_AutoFillDowntopic), If you set it to true, then column header is automatically stretched to fill the empty space below it and RowCount remain unchanged to 1 until you do not specify the [BandedGridColumn.RowCount Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBandedGridBandedGridColumn_RowCounttopic).

> Setting the RowCount property affects not only the column header's
>   height but the height of each cell within this column. The height of a
>   single data cell row, however, is specified by the GridView.RowHeight
>   property.

This is sample code from devExpress AdvancedBandedGridView sample app, which output image you have attached in your question:

```
// 
// gridBand3
// 
resources.ApplyResources(this.gridBand3, "gridBand3");
this.gridBand3.Columns.Add(this.colIcon);
this.gridBand3.OptionsBand.AllowSize = false;
this.gridBand3.OptionsBand.FixedWidth = true;
this.gridBand3.VisibleIndex = 2;
// 
// colIcon
// 
this.colIcon.AutoFillDown = true;
resources.ApplyResources(this.colIcon, "colIcon");
this.colIcon.ColumnEdit = this.repositoryItemPictureEdit1;
this.colIcon.FieldName = "Picture";
this.colIcon.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("colIcon.Image")));
this.colIcon.Name = "colIcon";
this.colIcon.OptionsColumn.AllowGroup = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.colIcon.OptionsColumn.AllowSize = false;
this.colIcon.OptionsColumn.AllowSort = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.colIcon.OptionsColumn.FixedWidth = true;
this.colIcon.OptionsFilter.AllowFilter = false;
this.colIcon.RowCount = 3;
```

**Example:**
View display based on these settings, here rows are 3, so RowCount property is set to 3 and AutoFillDown also set to true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are such an option for `GridView` and `BandedGridView` like [`GridOptionsView.RowAutoHeight`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_RowAutoHeighttopic) property. But for `AdvBandedGridView` this property is not in effect. All you can do is use [`BandedGridColumn.RowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCounttopic) property to increase the height of column cells:

```
advBandedGridView1.Columns["YourImageColumn"].RowCount = 3;
```